# Socket disconnect after read the textfile. How to maintain the connection?

Tags: c#, tcplistener

Here is my code:

A listener to wait for connection from client:

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{

            IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(args[1]);
            TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, Int32.Parse(args[2]));
            listener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
            while (true)
            {
                
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
                StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
               
                try
                {
                    if (stream.DataAvailable)
                    {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                        stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                        int recv = 0;
                        foreach (byte b in buffer)
                        {
                            if (b != 0)
                            {
                                recv++;
                            }
                        }
                        string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
                        Console.WriteLine("request received: " + request);
                        if (request != null)
                        {
                            string response = null;
                            response = apiQueryAndReponse(request, args[0]);
                            if (response != null)
                            {
                                byte[] byData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(response);
                                stream.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
                                stream.Flush();
                            }

                        }

                    }
                    
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
                    //sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
                }
            }
        }
```

Get and return the response:

```
private static string apiQueryAndReponse(string rec, String stagingfilepath)
        {
            String response = null;


            if (rec.Contains("GetTesterInfo"))
            {

               
                response = getLatestStatusOK("GetTesterInfo", stagingfilepath); 
            
                if (response != null)
                {

                    Console.WriteLine("Response: " + response + "," + fileline + "\n");
                  

                    fileline++;
                }
            }
               return response;
        }
```

Read the text file and get the response:

```
private static String getLatestStatusOK(String key, String filedir)
        {
            

            using (var fs = new FileStream(filedir, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
            {
                using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, Encoding.UTF8))
                {
                    while ((stagingfiledata = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
                    {

                        try
                        {
                            if (stagingfiledata.Contains(key))
                            {
                                String[] data = stagingfiledata.Split(",");
                                response = data[2];
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception exp)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("err message：" + exp.Message);
                        }


                    }

                }

            }
            return response;
        }
```

What I trying to do here: I will read a text file and get response to reply to client. But the socket will disconnect after access the text file.(I have tried connect with client without call the text file access function). I want to maintain connection and read text file when it necessary.

Comment: You have two issues.  One that a "Using" block when you exit the block will close the stream and dispose which is closing the connection.  Remove the "Using".  Second, when you read a file using a stream the operating system closes the stream when you get to the end of the data and send the app a "null".  A Network stream unless you close the steam you will not get a "null".  Instead you will get a EOF (end of file).  So you  are stuck in the while loop because you are testing null.  When sending data the receive end needs to know the end of data.  So terminate ascii data with a character.

Comment: i change from "Using" to string[] lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(filedir) to read text file. The socket also will disconnect, so which mean File.ReadAllLines also will exit the block and close the stream ?

Comment: It is the line above the FileStrream that is closing connection.

Comment: Could you provide some sample code to me? Therefore I can have some idea to change on it

Comment: I'm looking t the code carefully.  There is nothing the should close the connection.  What I think is the issue is the first three lines of the while loop (stream,sr,sw) should only be opened once.  So these three lines should be outside the while loop instead of inside the while loop.  You only have one connection and cannot open multiple streams to one connection.

Comment: Logs:
FINE : SENDING MESSAGE TO (Tester API): 14~GetTesterInfo
FINE : PARTIAL REPLY DETECTED FROM (Tester API). Received:

(Unload Setup) Button clicked
INFO : Unloading setup . . .
INFO : Can not connect to Tester API.

After I move the stream outside the loop it still the same. Will disconnect after read the text file. you may refer the logs I provided

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues with this code.

- **Your primary issue:** you are creating a new `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter` on each loop, and they dispose the underlying stream when they are garbage-collected.
- You aren't even using those readers and writers, you may as well remove them
- You are missing `using` in a number of places.
- The number of bytes received is returned from the `Read` function, you do not have to guesstimate by checking for `\0`.

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) 
{
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(args[1]);
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, Int32.Parse(args[2]));
    listener.Start();
    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.");
    using TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
    Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
    using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int recv = stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
            string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, recv);
            Console.WriteLine("request received: " + request);
            if (request != null)
            {
                string response = null;
                response = apiQueryAndReponse(request, args[0]);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    byte[] byData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                    stream.Write(byData, 0, byData.Length);
                    stream.Flush();
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.");
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
            //sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

There are other serious flaws with your design:

- TCP does not guarantee that a single write will become a single read on the other end of the wire. Chunks of data may be split or combined. It's a *stream*, not a messaging protocol.
- So you need a framing mechanism. The easiest one to use is to first pass the size of your data, then read that amount of bytes.
- You are also not able to handle multiple clients. You need to hand off each one to a `Task`.
- Corrollary to that, you should use `async` functions to improve performance and responsiveness.
- You should also have a cancellation token which you can use if someone presses CTRL+C.
- You probably shouldn't try to handle an exception and then continue. If an exception happens, log it and close the connection.

```cs
static CancellationTokenSource _cancellation = new();

static async Task Main(string[] args) 
{
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (sender, e) => _cancellation.Cancel();
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse(args[1]);
    TcpListener listener = new TcpListener(ipAddr, Int32.Parse(args[2]));
    listener.Start();
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for a connection.");
        TcpClient client = await listener.AcceptTcpClientAsync(_cancellation.Token);
        Console.WriteLine("Client accepted.");
        Task.Run(() => HandleClient(client), _cancellation.Token);
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    finally
    {
        listener.Stop();
    }
}

private async Task HandleClient(TcpClient client)
{
    using var _ = client;
    await using NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
    var lengthBuf = new byte[4];
    try
    {
        while (true)
        {
            await stream.ReadExactlyAsync(lengthBuf, 0, 4, _cancellation.Token);
            var length = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthBuf, 0);
            if(length > SomeMaxLengthHere || length <= 0)
                throw new Exception("Too long");

            byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
            await stream.ReadExactly(buffer, 0, length, _cancellation.Token);
            string request = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer, 0, length);
            Console.WriteLine("request received: " + request);
            if (request != null)
            {
                string response = apiQueryAndReponse(request, args[0]);
                if (response != null)
                {
                    byte[] byData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(response);
                    await stream.WriteAsync(byData, 0, byData.Length, _cancellation.Token);
                    await stream.FlushAsync(_cancellation.Token);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (OperationCanceledException)
    { //
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Something went wrong.");
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message.ToString());
        //sw.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: CancellationTokenSource _cancellation = new(); cant be used. It prompt a message said that "An Object reference is required a non-static field,method and property"

Comment: Yeah, needs to be `static` see edit

Comment: @Charlieface : What you did is nice, but nothing answers the question of why the connection closes.

Comment: Like I said: *"you are creating a new StreamReader and StreamWriter on each loop, and they dispose the underlying stream when they are garbage-collected."*